# How do I create a Managed Service Account in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a Managed Service Account on Windows 7. I've followed the steps in the [guide to Managed Service Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356(WS.10).aspx) to enable the Active Directory Powershell snap-in.

The first thing I notice is that when I do import-module ActiveDirectory, I get a warning

> 'Error initializing default drive: 'Unable to find a default server with Acitve Directory Web Services running.'

Then I get a similar error ("Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running") when I issue the command `new-adserviceaccount TrialManagementApp`.

I figure that I'm probably getting the errors about not being able to find the server because our Domain Server is Windows 2003, rather than 2008 R2, but should that make a difference? I don't need  the account to be on the domain, I just want to use it on my PC.

Does anybody have any insight as to what's going on here?

And as a supplementary question: given the problems I'm having relating to the Domain Server, are Managed Service Accounts supported in a Workgroup environment where there is no Domain Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2008R2 domains would have [Active Directory Web Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908%28WS.10%29.aspx) by default.  In a 2003/2008 domain, you will need to install [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=008940c6-0296-4597-be3e-1d24c1cf0dda&pf=true) before you can use the `ActiveDirectory` Powershell modules.

You cannot, in any supporting documentation I have read, use Managed Service Accounts  without an AD domain.